# Where are Google Cloud Vision API calls processed and can we specify it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

when making a call to the Cloud Vision API, where is the request processes (Europe, US...)?
Is there a way to specify that we want the request to be handled in a specific region or location?

Background: as part of the various data protection measures, we need to ensure that we know precisely where data is transferred and processed.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to specify the project and the location where you want to make the call.

If you are using the REST API you have a field called "parent" where you can optionally define the project-id and the location-id. See [this documentation] (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#request-body), the supported location-ids are us: USA country only, eu: The European Union. .

If you are using a client library, for example the [Python Client for Cloud Vision API](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#module-google.cloud.vision_v1), there is an optional parameter also called "parent" where you can specify the project-id and the location-id. The supported location-ids are us: USA country only, asia: East asia areas, like Japan, Taiwan, eu: The European Union.

Take a deep look to the documentation in order to clarify which regions are currently  available and take in consideration that if no parent is specified, a region will be chosen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are [regional endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes#December_13_2019) for Cloud Vision API.